# Laravel 4.1 Deployment - Production .env.php not being recognised

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, environment-variables, production-environment

For some reason, my production laravel app thinks that it is in the local environment.

**/var/www/appname/.env.php**

```
<?php

return 
[
    'APP_ENV'   =>  'production',
    'DB_HOST'   =>  'HIDDEN',
    'DB_NAME'   =>  'HIDDEN',
    'DB_PASSWORD'   =>  'HIDDEN'
];
```

**/var/www/appname/bootstrap/start.php**

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    return getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'local';
});
```

**/var/www/appname/app/config/database.php**

```
...
...
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'database'  => getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'username'  => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'  => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => 'lar_',
    ),
...
...
```

**`sudo php artisan env` (via SSH)**

```
`Current application environment: local
```

**`php artisan tinker` then `getenv('DB_NAME')`**

```
$ php artisan tinker
[1] > getenv('DB_NAME');
// false
```

So either my environment variables are not being set, or Laravel is not recognising my `.env.php` file for the production environment.

**Update**

With some help from Anultro on IRC, it appears that .env.php is not loaded yet. As such APP_ENV must be set before laravel tries to detect environments. This makes sense, because Laravel needs to know what environment is running before determining whether to use `.env.php` or `.env.local.php`.

Having said this, `.env.php` should still be used to store db credentials and secret keys etc... But I am still having a problem because the app is still returning false when I try to run `getenv('DB_NAME')`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I've never heard of Laravel automatically handling a `.env.php` for environment detection? Are you sure the file is being included somewhere?

Comment: @Quasdunk - http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration and https://laracasts.com/lessons/private-keys-go-here (you may need to pay for a subscription to gain access to the video).

Comment: @Quasdunk - you will also see that `.env.php` and `.env.local.php` are included in the default `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I actually wasn't aware of that! You live, you learn :) Unfortunatelly, I have no idea what the problem could be then. Maybe you could check the file permissions and make sure that `.env.php` is readable or that the application is allowed to set environment variables with any name. This may be helpful (especially the description concerning `safe_mode_allowed_env_vars`): http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php

Comment: laravel 4.1 is messing up big. i have a bit different problem. it detects the environment but fails to load the correct config files.... (4.0.9 runs fine with same codes) laravel 4.0.* were way better than this 4.1 couldn't help you with this as i am myself trying to find why the hack it is not loading proper files.

Comment: Hi all, please see updated question - semi-solution but environment variables still not being read by production application.

Comment: any update for this solution?

Comment: @Shiro - Set the environment variables on live server in httpd.conf file or via an include file. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all who want to know... to solve this issue, I just edited my httpd.conf file on the production server as follows:

```
SetEnv APP_ENV production
```

Now laravel knows that the app is in production.

If you are using nginx which I have now migrated my site to add the following where you pass scripts to the FCGI server in the active sites-available `/etc/nginx/sites-available/{sitename}`:

```
fastcgi_param APP_ENV production;
```

Comment: Gravy: Can you please tell us the location of httpd.conf? I am fighting for this half a day here and still the fight is on ....

Comment: @SHANKAR - Different for each operating system / setup. Mine is in `/usr/local/apache/conf` with CentOS 5.5. Do a google search for httpd.conf location and include your OS and version

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am on LAMP and was able to sort it out with out configuring httd.conf file. My problem was, I was using closer to define env variable (getenv('ENV')). Later on I defined into array and it did work after that. I just wrote it for future visitors. Thanks again.