# Reload .env constants in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-forge

I just changed a constant inside my .env file. The new value is shown up correctly with php-cli (via tinker), but not in my web app (php-fpm).

So far I've tried everything as suggested:

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
sudo service php7.0-fpm reload
```

.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

This will generate a cache config file in bootstrap/cache/config.php

```
php artisan config:clear
```

This will remove cache config file in bootstrap/cache/config.php

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

What exactly does does ? What type of cache does it clear?

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

This clear compile classes

```
composer dump-autoload
```

This will generate/update composer autoload file.

I have some .env variables that are not part of any config file. So it is useless for me to run any of the artisan commands.

None of the above php artisan commands don't deal directly with $_ENV.

Seems that $_ENV is stored somewhere in the server and laravel cannot update it once properties are populated.

The only solution I've found is restarting the server.

I'm running a Laravel Forge instance.

Comment: try these two `php artisan clear-compiled` and `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Take a look at this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126709/laravel-4-1-deployment-production-env-php-not-being-recognised) question. Might be similar issue.

Comment: I realized that it was because the queue worker has its own process running, so queue tasks won't use the updated $_ENV. Restarting the worker via supervisord, reloads $_ENV.

Comment: @JohnSmith you save me two years later. Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel not reading changes to .env file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420761/laravel-not-reading-changes-to-env-file)

Answer (score 14):

If it is cached and you need to reload it you can simply use:

`php artisan config:clear`

This will pull in any changes that you have since made.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete the config on file on: Bootstrap/cache/config.php

AS well you can try: php artisan config:cache or  php artisan cache:clear

Comment: inside bootstrap/cache/ there's only services.php

Comment: Try other options to clear cache (although it is just a guess) like: php artisan view:clear, php artisan config:clear.

Comment: Btw, the problem is in the DB, Email, or other configs?

Comment: None of them. I need to access custom .env variables for other purposes than config files.